# How to install ubuntu on Microsoft Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V?

Tags: installation, server, 10.10, virtualization, hyper-v

Is there a way (now or in the future) to install ubuntu-server-64 on a Microsoft Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V?

I tried this quide: http://www.panterlo.com/2010/10/10/ubuntu-10-10-and-hyper-v-r2/ but you're never sure if ubuntu starts or not and if it's up and running the network fails after a very short time.

---

2011-11-04 by V.M.:  And "How run Ubuntu Desktop v11.10 ( Or KUbuntu Desktop v11.10 ) as LiveCD as Guest in Hyper-V ?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this guide should help you :

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-10-4-in-hyper-v.aspx

Comment: up and running - thank you!

PS: This works only with the server-version. If you need the desktop-version - you have to install the server first then apt-get install ubuntu-dekstop. PPS: To gain mouse-access you should install teamviewer and start it with alt-f2